# Android - Scan MSI/Plessey barcode

Tags: android, zxing, scanning

I would like to scan MSI/Plessey barcodes in my app. I currently use Zxing SDK but it seems it can't read this barcode format.

Can somebody tell me how I can do that? Do you know a library that can read MSI/Plessey barcodes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch available which adds MSI support to zxing.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/zxing/9C7MwMUuJRw
Perhaps that could be a solution.